# Objective C Int to 2's Complement Conversion

Tags: c, binary, integer

I'm trying to convert my 16 bit integer to two's complement if it's negative.

At the moment, I'm using the One's complement operator. I figure I can use that, and then add 1 to the binary value to convert it to two's complement. However, I'm unable to do x = ~a + 1 because that just yields the integer value + 1.

If my process is correct, how can I add 1 to the binary integer? If not, what is the most appropriate way to convert a 16 bit integer to 2's complement in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

A two's complement is a kind of representation of signed numbers, not a value or an operation. On nearly all modern computers two's complements are the standard representation of signed integers. (And it is one of three allowed representations of integers in the standard.)

Therefore if you have any signed integral number, it *is* represented in two's complement. I think you want to have "the" two's complement of a positive number. This is simply the negative value, if your machine uses two's complements for signed numbers.

```
int positiveValue = 5; 
int twosComplement = -positiveValue;
```